# Center caption in Quarto

Tags: css, caption, quarto, reveal.js

Is there an easy way to center a caption in Quarto? I work with the `revealjs` format. I'd like to do this locally.

I've tried with `fig-cap-location="center"` but it does not work.

Reproducible example:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
---

## Centering the caption

![I want this to be centered](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png){fit-align="center"}
```

[image]

Comment: I have gone through docs and fig-cap-location="center" doesn't exist only options are available are top,bottom, and margin and by default captions come in center in official docs too so please provide some more detail that what is rendering in browser so it would be easy for us to help you.

Comment: That's a good point, maybe it's reveal.js specific that the caption comes not centered. But you can reproduce this, right? or does it come centered for you by default? There is no documentation on caption justification, AFAIK it's not covered here: https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#caption-locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is using css, e.g.

```
.caption{
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#figure-alignment, they say

> Note that figure captions are left aligned to accommodate longer caption text (which looks odd when center aligned).